# I am struggling finding out why am I getting a null pointer exception. I know it's because of the null but I can't seem find which one

Tags: java, pointers, null

Here is the code. When I started to run the program I entered the option number 1 and it gave me an error saying Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException. Any help would be appreciated.

The Database.txt should look like this

```
510421600;Shelley;Morgan
790701850;Holton;Jose
932371897;Hynes;Naomi
714797789;Kunkel;Dylan
878566780;Grisham;Ellie
810639750;Childs;Lillian
```

Code

```
import java.io.File;

import java.util.Scanner;

import java.io.*;

public class ListExample
{

    Node head;
    Node tail;

    public ListExample()
    {
        head = null;
    }

    public ListExample(Node head)
    {
        this.head = head;
    }

    //Load Database
    public void Database()
    {
        head = null;
        Node tmp = null; 
        Node lastFirst = tmp;
        Node lastSecond = tmp;
        Node lastThird = tmp;

        for(int i = 9;i >= 0; i--)
        {
            String L1 = Integer.toString(i);
            for(int j = 9;j >= 0; j--)
            {
                String L2 = Integer.toString(j);
                for(int k = 9;k >= 0; k--)
                {

                    String L3 = Integer.toString(k);
                    String allNum = L1 + L2 + L3 + "000000";

                    tmp = new Node(allNum);
                    tmp.third = lastThird;
                    tmp.fourth = lastThird;
                    lastThird = tmp;    
                }
                tmp.second = lastSecond;
                lastSecond = tmp;
            }
            tmp.first = lastFirst;
            lastFirst = tmp;    
        }
        head = tmp;
    }

    //Inserting Skip Search
    public void insertInSkip(String SSN, String lName, String fName)
    {

        Node tmp = head;

        while((tmp != null) && SSN.charAt(0) >= tmp.first.SSN.charAt(0) )
        {
            tmp = tmp.first;
        }
        while((tmp != null) && SSN.charAt(1) >= tmp.second.SSN.charAt(1) )
        {
            tmp = tmp.second;
        }
        while((tmp != null) && SSN.charAt(2) >= tmp.third.SSN.charAt(2) )
        {
            tmp = tmp.third;
        }
        System.out.println(SSN);
        System.out.println(tmp.fourth.SSN);
        System.out.println(SSN.compareTo(tmp.fourth.SSN));
        while((tmp != null) && (SSN.compareTo(tmp.fourth.SSN) > 0))
        {
            tmp = tmp.fourth;
        }
        if(SSN.compareTo(tmp.SSN) == 0)
        {
                return;
        }
        else
        {
            Node temp = new Node(SSN, fName, lName);
            temp.fourth = tmp.fourth;
            tmp.fourth = temp;
        }
        endTimer();  
    } 

    // SkipSearch method
    public void skipSearch(String SSN)
    {
        Node tmp = head;

        while((tmp.first != null) && (SSN.charAt(0) < tmp.first.SSN.charAt(0)))
        {
            tmp = tmp.first;
        }
        while((tmp.second != null) && SSN.charAt(1) < tmp.second.SSN.charAt(1))
        {
            tmp = tmp.second;
        }
        while((tmp.third != null) && SSN.charAt(2) < tmp.third.SSN.charAt(2))
        {
            tmp = tmp.third;
        }
        while((tmp.fourth != null) && SSN.charAt(3) < tmp.fourth.SSN.charAt(3))
        {
            tmp = tmp.fourth;
        }
        while(tmp.fourth != null)
        {
            tmp = tmp.fourth;
            if(tmp.SSN.equals(SSN))
            {
                System.out.println(tmp.toString()+"has been found.");
                endTimer();
                System.out.println("Search took: " + timeElapsed()+ " seconds");
            }
        }

    }  

    // Read the file Database.txt
   public void readFile(String data)
    {
        startTimer();
        File file = new File(data);
        String firstName = " ";
        int count = 0;
        try
        {
            Scanner scanner = new Scanner(file);
            while(scanner.useDelimiter(";") != null && scanner.hasNext())
            {
                String ssn = scanner.next();
                String lastN = scanner.next();
                if(scanner.useDelimiter("\r") != null)
                {
                    scanner.skip(";");
                    String firstN = scanner.next();
                    firstName = firstN;
                    if(scanner.hasNext())
                    {
                        scanner.skip("\r");
                        scanner.skip("\n");
                    }
                }
                insertInSkip(ssn, firstName, lastN);
                count++;
                if(count % 1000 == 0)
                {
                    System.out.print(".");
                } 
            }
            scanner.close();
            endTimer();
            System.out.println("Data loaded in " + timeElapsed() + " secs.");
        }
        catch(FileNotFoundException e)
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    } 

   // End of program
    public void endProg()
    {
        System.out.println("Program exiting..");
        System.exit(0);
    }

    public long startTimer()
    {
        return System.currentTimeMillis();
    }

    public long endTimer()
    {
        return System.currentTimeMillis();
    }

    public float timeElapsed()
    {
        return (endTimer() - startTimer()) / 1000;
    }

    //run the program
    public void run(ListExample list)
    {
        Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
        int option;
        System.out.println("Select an option: ");
        System.out.println("1. Load database\n2. Skip Search\n3. Exit ");
        option = scanner.nextInt();    
        while(true)
        {
            switch(option)
            {
            case 1:

                list.Database();
                list.readFile("Database.txt");
                break;

            case 2:
                System.out.println("Enter SSN: ");
                String ssn2 = scanner.next();
                list.skipSearch(ssn2);                
                break;

            case 3:
                endProg();
                break;

            default:
                System.out.println("Incorrect value entered. Please enter a number between 1 and 3.");
                System.out.println("Select an option: ");
                System.out.println("1. Load database\n2. Skip Search\n3. Exit ");
                option = scanner.nextInt();
                break;
            }
        System.out.println("Select an option: ");
        System.out.println("1. Load database\n2. Skip Search\n3. Exit ");
        option = scanner.nextInt();

        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        ListExample list = new ListExample();
        list.run(list);
    }
}


Node.java


public class Node {

    public String SSN, fName, lName, allNum;
    public Node first;
    public Node second;
    public Node third;
    public Node fourth;
    public Node head, tail, next;

    public Node(String allNum){
        this.allNum = allNum;
    }
    public Node(String SSN, String fName, String lName){
        this.SSN = SSN;
        this.fName = fName;
        this.lName = lName;
    }

}
```

Comment: You're aware of the fact that "Find my NullPointerException" questions get downvoted very quickly, yet you haven't told us what your error is. Please show us your stacktrace.

Comment: Did you try to debug your code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've debugged your code. So look at line

```
while((tmp != null) && SSN.charAt(0) >= tmp.first.SSN.charAt(0) )
```

tmp.first.SSN gives NULL, and you're trying to get charAt from it. Check it:

```
System.out.println(tmp.first.SSN);
```

So you can add some condition to prevent this exception.

Look at your insertInSkip method:

```
    //Inserting Skip Search
    public void insertInSkip(String SSN, String lName, String fName)
    {

        Node tmp = head;
//        System.out.println(tmp.first);
//        System.out.println(tmp.second);
//        System.out.println(tmp.third);
//        System.out.println(tmp.first.SSN);

        while((tmp != null) && (tmp.first.SSN != null) && SSN.charAt(0) >= tmp.first.SSN.charAt(0) ) // changed
        {
            tmp = tmp.first;
        }

        while((tmp != null) && (tmp.second.SSN != null) && SSN.charAt(1) >= tmp.second.SSN.charAt(1) ) // changed
        {
            tmp = tmp.second;
        }

        while((tmp != null) && (tmp.third.SSN != null) && SSN.charAt(2) >= tmp.third.SSN.charAt(2) ) // changed
        {
            tmp = tmp.third;
        }
        System.out.println("ssn="+SSN);
        System.out.println(tmp.fourth.SSN);
        if (tmp.fourth.SSN != null){  // changed
            System.out.println(SSN.compareTo(tmp.fourth.SSN));
        }

        while((tmp != null) && (tmp.fourth.SSN != null) && (SSN.compareTo(tmp.fourth.SSN) > 0)) // changed
        {
            tmp = tmp.fourth;
        }
        if(SSN.equals(tmp.SSN))
        {
                return;
        }
        else
        {
            Node temp = new Node(SSN, fName, lName);
            temp.fourth = tmp.fourth;
            tmp.fourth = temp;
        }
        endTimer();  
    }
```

Here's the output:

```
Select an option: 
1. Load database
2. Skip Search
3. Exit 
1
ssn=510421600
null
ssn=790701850
510421600
2
ssn=932371897
510421600
4
ssn=714797789
510421600
2
ssn=878566780
510421600
3
ssn=810639750
510421600
3
Data loaded in 0.0 secs.
Select an option: 
1. Load database
2. Skip Search
3. Exit
```

UPD SkipSearch :

```
// SkipSearch method
public void skipSearch(String SSN)
{
    Node tmp = head;
    //System.out.println(tmp);

    if (tmp != null) {
        while((tmp.first != null) 
                && (tmp.first.SSN != null) 
                && (SSN.charAt(0) < tmp.first.SSN.charAt(0))
                )
        {
            tmp = tmp.first;
        }
        while((tmp.second != null) 
                && (tmp.second.SSN != null) 
                && SSN.charAt(1) < tmp.second.SSN.charAt(1))
        {
            tmp = tmp.second;
        }
        while((tmp.third != null) 
                && (tmp.third.SSN != null) 
                && SSN.charAt(2) < tmp.third.SSN.charAt(2))
        {
            tmp = tmp.third;
        }
        while((tmp.fourth != null) 
                && (tmp.fourth.SSN != null) 
                && SSN.charAt(3) < tmp.fourth.SSN.charAt(3))
        {
            tmp = tmp.fourth;
        }
        while(tmp.fourth != null)
        {
            tmp = tmp.fourth;
            if(tmp.SSN.equals(SSN))
            {
                System.out.println(tmp.toString()+"has been found.");
                endTimer();
                System.out.println("Search took: " + timeElapsed()+ " seconds");
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you, it did work! Do you have any idea why isn't the SkipSearch method working (which is the option number 2)?

Comment: Thanks for accepting answer. It is the same issue. Variable tmp gives NULL and you get Exception. I've updated the answer. However, you should understand that these answers just preventing Exceptions. I think that it would be better for you to change this decisions to match your business logics (or technical task). And if you get Exceptions you should look to stacktrace, what is the character of exception and in which line it occurs. Thank you.